# How to find the optimal cut-off point to minimize both the FNR and FPR in R?

Tags: r, classification, roc

I should find the optimal threshold to minimize both the false positive rate and false negative rate. An equal weight between these two rates should be assumed. I write the following code:

```
data=read.csv( url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/propublica/compas-analysis/master/compas-scores-two-years.csv"), sep=",")
library(ROCR)
pred=prediction(data$decile_score/10, data$two_year_recid)
perf=performance(pred, measure="fnr",x.measure="fpr")

opt.cut = function(perf, pred)
{
    cut.ind = mapply(FUN=function(x, y, p){
        d = (x - 0)^2 + (y-1)^2
        ind = which(d == min(d))
        c(False_negative_rate = 1-y[[ind]], False_positive_rate = x[[ind]], 
            cutoff = p[[ind]])
    }, perf@x.values, perf@y.values, pred@cutoffs)
}

print(opt.cut(perf, pred))
```

It throws out this result:

```
                   [,1]
False_negative_rate    0
False_positive_rate    0
cutoff               Inf
```

However, I think there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: Your first values in `perf@x.values, perf@y.values, pred@cutoffs` are causing your results, they are 1, 0 and Inf, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think your code is flawed from a logical point of view. You said You want to

> minimize both the false positive rate and false negative rate

But then you minimize

> `d = (x - 0)^2 + (y-1)^2`

which is `1 - FNR` which is the *True Positive Rate*.

Thus, assuming you want to minimize *FPR* and *FNR*  you could simply do:

```r
pred@cutoffs[[1]][which.min(sqrt(perf@x.values[[1]] ^ 2 + perf@y.values[[1]] ^ 2))]

# [1] 0.5
```

(no need to use extra loops as `R` is nicely vectorized)

To verify this result, you can simply calculate  *FPR* and *FNR* yourself for different cutoffs (which will give you the same results as `performance` of course, but it is a good exercise to understand the principles):

```r
 t(sapply(pred@cutoffs[[1]], function(co) {
   prediction <- factor(ifelse(data$decile_score / 10 < co, 0, 1), 0:1)
   confusion_matrix <- table(data$two_year_recid, prediction)
   fpr <- confusion_matrix[1, 2] / sum(confusion_matrix[1, ])
   fnr <- confusion_matrix[2, 1] / sum(confusion_matrix[2, ])
   c(cutoff = co, fpr = fpr, fnr = fnr, dist = sqrt(fpr ^ 2 + fnr ^2))
}))

#       cutoff        fpr        fnr      dist
#  [1,]    Inf 0.00000000 1.00000000 1.0000000
#  [2,]    1.0 0.02195307 0.90895109 0.9092162
#  [3,]    0.9 0.06056018 0.79975392 0.8020436
#  [4,]    0.8 0.10143830 0.69209474 0.6994890
#  [5,]    0.7 0.16250315 0.58443556 0.6066071
#  [6,]    0.6 0.23391370 0.47431560 0.5288581
#  [7,]    0.5 0.32349230 0.37403876 0.4945223 #### <<- Minimum
#  [8,]    0.4 0.43325763 0.27130114 0.5111912
#  [9,]    0.3 0.55084532 0.18486620 0.5810388
# [10,]    0.2 0.71435781 0.09474008 0.7206128
# [11,]    0.1 1.00000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Nice answer. The same solution can be reached using the `cutpointr` package: `cp <- cutpointr(data, decile_score, two_year_recid, method = maximize_metric, metric = sum_sens_spec)`

Answer (score 1):

The first values in `perf@x.values`, `perf@y.values`, `pred@cutoffs` are causing your results, they are 1, 0 and Inf, respectively. In order to remove them, loop
through each list member and extract the vectors without the 1st element.

```
library(ROCR)

opt.cut = function(perf, pred) {
  #
  x.values <- lapply(perf@x.values, `[`, -1)
  y.values <- lapply(perf@y.values, `[`, -1)
  cutoffs <- lapply(pred@cutoffs, `[`, -1)
  #
  cut.ind <- mapply(FUN=function(x, y, p){
    d <- x^2 + y^2
    ind <- which.min(d)
    c(False_negative_rate = y[[ind]], 
      False_positive_rate = x[[ind]], 
      cutoff = p[[ind]])
  }, x.values, y.values, cutoffs)
  cut.ind
}

pred <- prediction(data$decile_score/10, data$two_year_recid)
perf <- performance(pred, measure = "fnr", x.measure = "fpr")

opt.cut(perf, pred)
#                         [,1]
#False_negative_rate 0.3740388
#False_positive_rate 0.3234923
#cutoff              0.5000000
```

Comment: While this solves OP's apparent problem, the real problem is that the OP used the wrong objective function to minimize in the first place,

Comment: @thothal You are right, I hadn't thought it well. With the edit it now gives your result, with the OP's output format.